# Linq-to-SQL using stored proc in SQL Server 2000 missing mapping

Tags: linq-to-sql, sql-server-2000

I using SQL Server 2000 and running SQLMetal to generate my `Mappings.xml` and my DataContext code

This all works fine for CRUD to a table.

Now I need to use stored procedures to perform my CRUD to the table with the same structure.

I know how to do this using the nice designer in VS 2010 and to a SQL Server 2008, but how do you do this by hand with SQL Server 2000?

Answer (score 2):

The ***/sprocs*** option in the **SQLMetal** command line options extracts the mappings for Stored Procedures from the database. The mappings would be similar to the table/view mappings that you're seeing currently.

So a sample command would look like.

```
sqlmetal /server:myserver /database:northwind /sprocs /map:Mappings.xml
```

Refer this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386987%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for detailed list of command line switches.

Be aware of the limitations of Linq To SQL with MS SQL Server 2000, refer this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399342.aspx) for some of the known limitations.